# Rails Migration for Deleted Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migrate

I jumped on an existing project and when I run `rake db:migrate` it gives me an error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "homes" does not exist`. I can see that it existed in the past, but it was deleted later. I tried `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you have the migration which creates the table `homes`? I guess the migration creating the homes table is deleted.

Comment: I do have it, it's there

Comment: Okay, does the file giving you error exists before the homes migration?

Comment: It was created in January 2017, and deleted in May 2017, the datestamp is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by simply commenting everything within change or up method of migration and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or `rake db:migrate`

Their is one more way you can add table within your database and run migration command. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run command rake db:migrate:reset to resolve the issue